# Execute code after 2 API calls response

Tags: node.js, express, request

Hello I´m making two API calls to make some checks and I want to execute code after both calls complete.

```
var firstCall = request.get('/first', function (error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body)
})

var secondCall = request.get('/second', function (error, response, body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body)
})
```

Ideally I want to do something like this (using underscore for the example)

```
if (_.isEmpty(firstCall) && _.isEmpty(secondCall)) {
    // execute code here because both calls are empty.
}
```

I believe I need to implement promises but I´m not sure how to do that for the request module. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using promises:

(Based on the code that you shared I assume that you are using an old version of node, so I won't use ES6 syntax)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');

function get(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, function(error, response, body) {
      if (error) return reject(error);
      resolve(JSON.parse(body));
    });
  });
}

var firstCall = get('/first');
var secondCall = get('/second');
Promise.all([firstCall, secondCall]).then(function (results) {
  if(_.every(results, _.isEmpty)) {
    // Do whatever you need to do
  }
})
```

ES6 version:

```
const get = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
  request.get(url, (error, response, body) =>
    error ? reject(error) : resolve(JSON.parse(body))
  )
);

const firstCall = get('/first');
const secondCall = get('/second');
Promise.all([firstCall, secondCall]).then(results => {
  if(_.every(results, _.isEmpty)) {
    // Do whatever you need to do
  }
})
```

Comment: hello I´m using node v7.0.0 what´s wrong with the syntax?

Comment: @handsome: well, you are not using any ES6 syntax, so I thought that you were using an old version of node.js. You are using `var` instead of using `let`/`const`, you  are not using arrow functions, you are not using Promises, etc. There is nothing wrong with your syntax, it's just pre-ES6, that's it.

BTW: does this answer solve your problem? If it does, would you mind marking it as accepted?

Comment: thanks @josep for your explanation. Do I need to use a module for that? can I change the code to create raw promises?

Comment: @handsome if you are using v7 you don't need to use bluebird, you could just use standard ES6 promises. However, in most node projects I would still use bluebird [given the fact that it will perform a lot better](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/benchmarks.html).

Comment: no worries @handsome, I just updated my answer with the ES6 equivalent version of the code :-)

Comment: I saw it thanks. one more question!
can I do Promise.all([firstCall,method(), secondCall.method()]).then(function (results) {  (let´s assume that get returns method() thanks!

Comment: if `method()` returns a promise: yes, but I've never seen anything like that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130171/discussion-between-handsome-and-josep).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `async` module for that. Use `async.serial` to serially execute functions and `async.parallel` for parallel  execution of functions. You can write code which is supposed to execute after both functions execution in callback function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the promise or promise module like async.

If you first 2 API are independent then use async.parallel else you can use 
async.series.

```
async.parallel({
    firstCall: function(callback){
        request.get('/first', function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                return callback(error);
            };
            return callback(null,JSON.parse(body));
        });
    },
    secondCall: function(callback){
        request.get('/second', function (error, response, body) {
            if(error){
                return callback(error);
            };
            return callback(null,JSON.parse(body));
        });
    }
},
function(err, results) {
    if (_.isEmpty(results.firstCall) && _.isEmpty(results.secondCall))      {
        // execute code here because both calls are empty.
    }
});
```

For dependent API call look [async.series](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#seriestasks-callback);